# How to read a file form a Django model FileField

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model in Django:

```
class Batch(CustomModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name=_("Producto"), on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='batchs')
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Fecha de Inicio"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    due_date = models.DateField(_("Fecha de Vencimiento"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    states = models.ManyToManyField(State, verbose_name=_("Estados"))
    source_file = models.FileField(_("Archivo de origen"), upload_to=None, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Lote")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Lotes")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}]{}/{}/{}".format(self.id, self.product.id, self.start_date, self.due_date)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        tokens_string = self.source_file.open()
        tokens = tokens_string.split('\n')
        print(tokens)
```

As you can see, in method `save()` I try to print the content of the file being uploaded to field ' source_file`. This is the file being uploaded:

file.txt

```
867670000460
867670000693
867670001445
867670001519
867670001597
```

When I do `print(tokens)`, I get a single long string:

```
b'867670000460\r\n867670000693\r\n867670001445\r\n867670001519\r\n867670001597\r\n867670002554'
```

I tried to split the string using `tokens_string.split('\n')`, but I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/hugovillalobos/Documents/Code/cinetogoproject/backend/cinetogo/inventory/models.py", line 37, in save
    tokens = tokens_string.split('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I get each line of the file separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a binary string.

Use   `tokens = tokens_string.decode("utf-8").split('\n')`.